# Openssl version upgrade from Microsoft hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops, openssl, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

We are using Microsoft hosted agent to generate self signed certificate from Azure DevOps pipeline using openssl command.  Noticed that agents are using openssl version 1.1.1.0

[image]

Based on [OpenSSL Security Advisory [15 March 2022]](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20220315.txt) recommendation, need to upgrade openssl from 1.1.1 to 1.1.1n.
[image]

How can we perform openssl version upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

You're using Microsoft's agent. You've traded flexibility for convenience. You don't control the software on the agent; Microsoft does. Thus, you have two options:

- Wait for Microsoft to update their hosted agents
- Create and maintain your own private agents

Comment: Is there any time line to update OpenSSL

Comment: @RajakumarBabu, you might need to direct your feedback for the Azure DevOps team e.g. using https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest